# Download files without dialog window selenium

Tags: python, docker, selenium, download, selenium-chromedriver

I have a cod.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def browser():
    selenium_grid_url = os.getenv('SELENIUM_HOST', "not_found") + "/wd/hub"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'ru-RU',
                                                     'download.default_directory': f'{directory}',
                                                     "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                                                     "download.directory_upgrade": True,
                                                     "safebrowsing.enabled": True
                                                     }
                                           )
    print(f"\nStart Chrome browser.. {selenium_grid_url}")
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    browser = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor=selenium_grid_url,
                               options=chrome_options)
    yield browser
    print("\nClose Chrome..")
    browser.quit()
```

I have a docker + python + pytest + selenium + Chrome + selenium host and prefs
But it doesn't work. I want save to file without dialog window. But test don`t save files. How can I understand the reason?
And... Downloading files works on Windows, but not docker on linux.
P.S
I have this path in docker env for chrome download and python
DOWNLOAD_FOLDER=/app/download_files
FOLDER_FOR_TEST_FILES=/app/test_files

My cod for check files

```
new_list_download_files = next(os.walk(f'{directory}'))[2]
        first_doc = new_list_download_files[0]
        second_doc = new_list_download_files[1]
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.12-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ARG REQUIREMENTS=${REQUIREMENTS:-requirements.txt}
COPY ./${REQUIREMENTS} /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT  ["python"]
```

Comment: Are you not able to see logs?

Comment: @Chayan Bansal Hm... I don`t now where i can see log? And which logs - browser or where?

Comment: Try this command `docker logs --follow <container ID>`

Comment: @ChayanBansal I took the log from the browser and found no errors there. Apparently the problem is in the docker+linux path, because it works in windows

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: @ChayanBansal yes. Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 days.
In the end, all you had to do was use docker-volumes.
In docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  data-volume:
  download-volume:
    external: true
    name: selenium_downloads
```